# split words in MIPS

Tags: mips

I want to separate the words in a sentence and I want to pass each of these words to the bottom line in MIPS like this my string: Hello my name is Jack, output should be like this
Output:
Hello
my
name
is
Jack
Can anyone help me ?
I started like this;

```
.data 
string1: .space 100    
newLine: .asciiz "\n"    
ask: .asciiz "Enter string: "    
newstring: .asciiz "New string: "

.text

main:
```

Comment: Ok, good start. What's preventing further progress?  The next step would be asking the user for the string, are you asking about that?  If so, then just look around a bit more.  If not, then maybe try looking to see how some whole sample programs work.  Either way, there's lots of examples out there for study.  Or else share what you're stuck with, if it is something technical.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So you're trying to print each word of the string on its own line?